# get friend's profile picture url or profile picture using graph api v2.3 in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

```
 new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                        "/"+userId+"/picture",
                                        null,
                                        HttpMethod.GET,
                                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */             Log.e("new Response","----"+response);
                                            }
                                        }
                                ).executeAsync();
                                }
```

I am getting response like below.

**Response:**

> responseCode: 200, graphObject:
>   {"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000�Photoshop"},
>   error: null}

Comment: Can someone please tell me, is it possible or not?

Comment: Of course, I am trying to retrieve the profile picture of all authorized friend who have used my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating  `executeGraphPathRequestAsync` request, create simple `GET` request.

```
graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID/picture
```

Check below link to get image from remote url:

[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android/2472175#2472175)